# com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[11.0, 12) what are "11.0" and 12 meaning?

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk

I upgrade the facebook unity editor to 11.0.0 and I found that in Dependencies.xml file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dependencies>
    <androidPackages>
        <androidPackage spec="com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0" />
        <androidPackage spec="com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[11.0, 12)" />
        <androidPackage spec="com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[11.0, 12)" />
        <androidPackage spec="com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[11.0, 12)" />
        <androidPackage spec="com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[11.0, 12)" />
        <androidPackage spec="com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices:[11.0, 12)" />
    </androidPackages>
    <iosPods>
        <iosPod name="FBSDKCoreKit_Basics" version="~> 11.0" />
        <iosPod name="FBSDKCoreKit" version="~> 11.0" />
        <iosPod name="FBSDKLoginKit" version="~> 11.0" />
        <iosPod name="FBSDKShareKit" version="~> 11.0" />
        <iosPod name="FBSDKGamingServicesKit" version="~> 11.0" />
    </iosPods>
</dependencies>
```

So what are "11.0" and "12" at the end of the android package line meaning?

Comment: Not an expert on unity, but it looks like it takes the max version between 11.0 (inclusive because the `[` sign) to 12 (exclusive because the `)` sign)

Comment: Sounds like a good method to allow auto upgrade, but only minor releases (11.x) to not break the api

Comment: [You might find this intresting](https://semver.org/)